# Used :---- setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('sing-in-block').style.display='none';}, 1000);

Tags: javascript

Used settimeout () function which will the html component will appear for 1 sec on pageload.  I want this component not to loaded,should i set   settimeout () function  delay=0ms?  Or is there any  way i can hidethat component.

Comment: When should the component get loaded? Also, provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

For hide a component you just add some style to it:

```css
#sign-in-block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div> Some hidden content below  </div>
<div id="sign-in-block"> I'm hidden </div>
```